# jQuery UI ipod Drill Down Menu

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

While I've been trying to figure out how to neatly display very long navigational links, i came across this [jQuery IOS Drill Down Menu](http://jamesarosen.github.com/jquery-ui/demos/menu/ios-menu.html) plugin (source article: [jQuery Wiki Menu](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137997/Menu)). I've tried implementing it as a widget into my solution but i think the problems lie in some of its deprecated methods such as .left and and .right.

I'm currently using jquery 1.9.0 and jQuery UI 1.10.0.

I'm not really experienced in writing widgets/upgrading them so any help with this would be greatly appreciated as it seems like a really useful widget for displaying complex menus.

**CSS Snipet:**

```
    .ios-style, .ios-style ul, .ios-style ol { background: #fff; height: 200px; padding: 2px; width: 260px; }
    .ios-style { overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; }
    .ios-style::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 5px; height: 5px; }
    .ios-style::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.6); border-radius: 4px; }
    .ios-style ul, .ios-style ol { overflow-y: visible; border: none; }
    .ios-style.ui-menu-icons .ui-menu-item a { position: inherit; }
    .ios-style .ui-menu-item a { cursor: pointer; outline: none; }
```

**jQuery Widget Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.widget( "ui.iosMenu", {
        options: {
            backText:      'Back',
            slideDuration: 400,
            slideEasing:   'linear'
        },

        _insertBackButtons: function() {
            this.element.find( 'li ul, li ol' ).prepend(
                $( '<li>' +
                     '  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-w"></span>' +
                     '  <a href="#menu-back" class="ios-menu-back-link">' +
                                this.options.backText +
                     '  </a>' +
                     '</li>'
            ) );
            return this;
        },

        _create: function( options ) {
            var iosMenu = this;

            iosMenu
                ._insertBackButtons()
                .element
                    .addClass( 'ios-style' )
                    .menu({
                        // When a submenu shows up, place it just to the right
                        // of the current menu. Later, we'll slide it into view.
                        position: {
                            my: 'left top',
                            at: 'right top',
                            of: iosMenu.element
                        }
                    });

            var menu = iosMenu.element.data( 'menu' );

            // Override menu#select to account for nesting and back buttons:
            menu.select = function( event ) {
                if ( menu.active && menu.active.find( '> .ios-menu-back-link' ).length ) {
                    // if you selected "back", go back:
                    menu.focus( event, menu.active );
                    if ( menu.left( event ) ) {
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();
                } else if ( menu.active && menu.active.find( '> ul' ).length ) {
                    // if you selected something with children, show the children:
                    menu.focus( event, menu.active );
                    if ( menu.right( event ) ) {
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    menu._trigger( 'select', event, { item: menu.active } );
                }
            };

            // Override menu#left to enable sliding behavior:
            menu.left = function( event ) {
                var newItem = this.active && this.active.parents( 'li:not(.ui-menubar-item) ').first(),
                        self        = this,
                        parent;
                if ( newItem && newItem.length ) {
                  newItem.find( '> a' ).addClass( 'ui-state-focus' ).removeClass( 'ui-state-active' );
                    parent = this.active.parent();
                    parent
                        .attr( 'aria-hidden', 'true' )
                        .attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' )
                        .animate({
                            left: self.element.css( 'width' )
                        }, iosMenu.options.slideDuration, iosMenu.options.slideEasing, function() {
                            parent.hide();
                            self.focus( event, newItem );
                        })
                    return true;
                } else if ( event && event.which === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE ) {
                    // #left gets called both for left-arrow and escape. If it's the
                    // latter and we're at the top, fire a "close" event:
                    self._trigger( 'close', event );
                }
            };

            // Override menu#_open to enable sliding behavior:
            var menuOpenWithoutSliding = menu._open;
            menu._open = function ( submenu ) {
                menuOpenWithoutSliding.call( this, submenu );
                submenu.animate({
                    left: 0
                }, iosMenu.options.slideDuration, iosMenu.options.slideEasing);
            };

            // Override menu#_startOpening so that hovering doesn't
            // initiate the sliding:
            menu._startOpening = function() {
                clearTimeout( this.timer );
            }
        },

        destroy: function() {
          var menu = this.element && this.element.data( 'menu' );
            menu && menu.destroy();
        }
    });

    $(function() {
        var list    = $( '#breakfast-menu' );
        var firstLI = list.find( 'li' ).first();
        list
            .iosMenu()
            .focus()
            .menu( 'focus', {}, firstLI )
            .bind( 'menuselect', function( event, ui ) {
                $('#log').append( '<li>' + $(ui.item).text() + '</li>' );
            });
    });
</script>
```

**Runtime Error**

```
    var menu = iosMenu.element.data( 'menu' );
```

Throws a 'menu' undefined error in firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use those other changes. I wanted to use a CDN version of jquery UI, so I didn't mess with those. Here is my compatible version.

```
$.widget( "ui.iosMenu", {
    options: {
        backText:      'Back',
        slideDuration: 200,
        slideEasing:   'linear'
    },

    _insertBackButtons: function() {
        this.element.find( 'li ul, li ol' ).prepend(
            $( '<li class="ui-menu-item ios-menu-back-link" role="presentation">' +
                 '  <a href="#menu-back" class="ui-corner-role" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" >' +
                '   <span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-w"></span>' +
                            this.options.backText +
                 '  </a>' +
                 '</li>'
        ) );
        return this;
    },

    _create: function( options ) {
        var iosMenu = this;

        iosMenu
            ._insertBackButtons()
            .element
                .addClass( 'ios-style' )
                .menu({
                    // When a submenu shows up, place it just to the right
                    // of the current menu. Later, we'll slide it into view.
                    position: {
                        my: 'left top',
                        at: 'right top',
                        of: iosMenu.element
                    }
                });

        var menu = iosMenu.element.data( 'uiMenu' );

        // Override menu#select to account for nesting and back buttons:
        menu.select = function( event ) {
            //menu.active = menu.active || $( event.target ).closest( ".ui-menu-item" ); //new random line
            if ( menu.active && menu.active.find('a').attr("href") == "#menu-back" ) {
                // if you selected "back", go back:
                menu.focus( event, menu.active );
                menu.collapse( event );
                /*
                if ( menu.collapse( event ) ) {
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }
                event.preventDefault();*/
            } else if ( menu.active && menu.active.find( '> ul' ).length ) {
                // if you selected something with children, show the children:
                menu.focus( event, menu.active );
                menu.expand( event );
                /*
                if ( menu.expand( event ) ) {
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }
                event.preventDefault();*/
            } else {
                menu._trigger( 'select', event, { item: menu.active } );
            }
        };
        /*
        // Override menu#expand to add return true:
        menu.expand = function( event ) {
            var newItem = this.active &&
                this.active
                    .children( ".ui-menu " )
                    .children( ".ui-menu-item" )
                    .first();

            if ( newItem && newItem.length ) {
                this._open( newItem.parent() );

                // Delay so Firefox will not hide activedescendant change in expanding submenu from AT
                this._delay(function() {
                    this.focus( event, newItem );
                });
                return true;
            }
        };*/

        // Override menu#collapse to enable sliding behavior:
        menu.collapse = function( event ) {
            var newItem = this.active && this.active.parents( 'li:not(.ui-menubar-item) ').first(),
                    self        = this,
                    parent;
            if ( newItem && newItem.length ) {
              newItem.find( '> a' ).addClass( 'ui-state-focus' ).removeClass( 'ui-state-active' );
                parent = this.active.parent();
                parent
                    .attr( 'aria-hidden', 'true' )
                    .attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' )
                    .animate({
                        left: self.element.css( 'width' )
                    }, iosMenu.options.slideDuration, iosMenu.options.slideEasing, function() {
                        parent.hide();
                        self.focus( event, newItem );
                    })
                //return true;
            } else if ( event && event.which === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE ) {
                // #left gets called both for left-arrow and escape. If it's the
                // latter and we're at the top, fire a "close" event:
                self._trigger( 'close', event );
            }
        };




        // Override menu#_open to enable sliding behavior:
        var menuOpenWithoutSliding = menu._open;
        menu._open = function ( submenu ) {
            menuOpenWithoutSliding.call( this, submenu );

            submenu.animate({
                left: 0,
                height: menu.element[0].clientHeight - 4 ,
                width: menu.element[0].clientWidth 
            }, iosMenu.options.slideDuration, iosMenu.options.slideEasing);
        };

        // Override menu#_startOpening so that hovering doesn't
        // initiate the sliding:
        menu._startOpening = function( submenu ) {
            clearTimeout( this.timer );
            // Don't open if already open fixes a Firefox bug that caused a .5 pixel
            // shift in the submenu position when mousing over the carat icon
            if ( submenu.attr( "aria-hidden" ) !== "true" ) {
                return;
            }
        }
    },

    destroy: function() {
      var menu = this.element && this.element.data( 'uiMenu' );
        menu && menu.destroy();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's pretty good, works quite smoothly. Only a few graphical issues which may be the browser but +1 :).

Comment: Only issue i can see is there is slight bleed from the menu underneath on the right (assume this is from where the scrollbar positioning is).

Comment: As a quick fix i commented out (width: menu.element[0].clientWidth) and let the width be decided by the parent div. Seems to do the trick and thanks again. Might be an idea to submit this to jquery as it is a pretty handy themerolled menu.

Comment: Hmm, you must be using it in a somewhat different way than me. If I comment out that line, my submenus become only about half the correct width, and with that line, they seem to be perfect. This needs a bit of work that I can't really do myself, since I'm not expert enough. In addition to the above mentioned problem, there is no easy way to "refresh" this menu. I had a hard time figuring out how to add the BackLinks if I changed the menu. Also, I don't know what all that commented out code was originally for and if it's still needed in some cases. Glad you liked it.

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same error as well. Took me quite some time to find the culprit, but here it goes:

**jquery.ui.menu.js**

added

```
this.mouseHandled = false;
```

to collapseAll and expand functions blur function `(within _create)` replaced with version from 1.9.0

**jquery.ui.widget.js**

added

```
$.data( element, this.widgetName, this );
```

to `_createWidget` function

**jquery-ui.iosmenu.js**

added

```
menu.active = menu.active || $( event.target ).closest( ".ui-menu-item" );
```

to `menu.selec`t

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use this code in a single page application and have to avoid using "href="menu-back" use a rel="" attribute instead.

```
 $.widget( "ui.iosMenu", {
    options: {
        backText:      'Back',
        slideDuration: 200,
        slideEasing:   'linear'
    },

    _insertBackButtons: function() {
        this.element.find( 'li ul, li ol' ).prepend(
        $( '<li class="ui-menu-item ios-menu-back-link" role="presentation">' +
                 '  <a rel="#menu-back" class="ui-corner-role" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" >' +
                '   <span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-w"></span>' +
                            this.options.backText +
                 '  </a>' +
                 '</li>'
        ) );
        return this;
    },

    _create: function( options ) {
        var iosMenu = this;

        iosMenu
            ._insertBackButtons()
            .element
                .addClass( 'ios-style' )
                .menu({
                    // When a submenu shows up, place it just to the right
                    // of the current menu. Later, we'll slide it into view.
                    position: {
                        my: 'left top',
                        at: 'right top',
                        of: iosMenu.element
                    }
                });

        var menu = iosMenu.element.data( 'uiMenu' );

        // Override menu#select to account for nesting and back buttons:
        menu.select = function( event ) {

             if ( menu.active && menu.active.find('a').attr("rel") == "#menu-back" ) {   
                // if you selected "back", go back:
                menu.focus( event, menu.active );
                menu.collapse( event );

            } else if ( menu.active && menu.active.find( '> ul' ).length ) {
                // if you selected something with children, show the children:
                menu.focus( event, menu.active );
                menu.expand( event );

            } else {
                menu._trigger( 'select', event, { item: menu.active } );
            }
        };


        // Override menu#collapse to enable sliding behavior:
        menu.collapse = function( event ) {
            var newItem = this.active && this.active.parents( 'li:not(.ui-menubar-item) ').first(),
                    self        = this,
                    parent;
            if ( newItem && newItem.length ) {
              newItem.find( '> a' ).addClass( 'ui-state-focus' ).removeClass( 'ui-state-active' );
                parent = this.active.parent();
                parent
                    .attr( 'aria-hidden', 'true' )
                    .attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' )
                    .animate({
                        left: self.element.css( 'width' )
                    }, iosMenu.options.slideDuration, iosMenu.options.slideEasing, function() {
                        parent.hide();
                        self.focus( event, newItem );
                    })
                //return true;
            } else if ( event && event.which === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE ) {

                self._trigger( 'close', event );
            }
        };

        // Override menu#_open to enable sliding behavior:
        var menuOpenWithoutSliding = menu._open;
        menu._open = function ( submenu ) {
            menuOpenWithoutSliding.call( this, submenu );

            submenu.animate({
                left: 0,
                height: menu.element[0].clientHeight - 4 ,
                width: menu.element[0].clientWidth 
            }, iosMenu.options.slideDuration, iosMenu.options.slideEasing);
        };

        // Override menu#_startOpening so that hovering doesn't
        // initiate the sliding:
        menu._startOpening = function( submenu ) {
            clearTimeout( this.timer );
            // Don't open if already open fixes a Firefox bug that caused a .5 pixel
            // shift in the submenu position when mousing over the carat icon
            if ( submenu.attr( "aria-hidden" ) !== "true" ) {
                return;
            }
        }
    },

    destroy: function() {
      var menu = this.element && this.element.data( 'uiMenu' );
        menu && menu.destroy();
    }
});
```

UPDATE:  To support jQuery 2.1.0, I had to change this line...

```
var menu = iosMenu.element.data( 'uiMenu' );
```

into this

```
var menu = iosMenu.element.data( 'ui-menu' );
```

I also had loaded jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js just in case anyone else has a similar issue.